# Finding a value of clicked element

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

So. I'm trying to make something like a web shop. I've connected the database and everything works perfectly fine. But now I want to make page for products description. When someone click on specific product, how to tell JS that it needs to shows only that products data. How to point that product. Hope you understand.
I'm using `node`, `express` and `ejs`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by adding using `display` property set `display: none` and then on the click set `display: block`. hope that solves ur problem. but Add some code that u tried to understand the problem better and no one here to code for you.

```js
$('.product').click( function() {
  $('.detail').css('display','block')
});
```

```css
.product {
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#ccc;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.detail {
  display:none;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
    product
</div>
<div class="detail">
    product detail
</div>
```

part